# Obtener una dirección de memoria de algun proceso escaneando array of bytes

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando emular el escaneo de direcciones de memoria por `array of bytes` de Cheat Engine, lo que hice funciona exactamente igual que Cheat Engine con un único problema... Es lento, Cheat Engine muestra mas de 4 millones de resultados en menos de 2 segundos, mientras el mio puede tardar minutos escaneando todos los bloques de memoria para obtener los resultados, lo que me parece realmente extraño es como Cheat Engine logra obtener las direcciones tan rápidamente.

```
buffer = pattern.Split(' ').Select(by => (byte)Convert.ToInt32(by.ToUpper(), 16)).ToArray();

for (int i = 3; i < MemoryRegion.Count; i++)
{
   int baseAddress = (int)MemoryRegion[i].BaseAddress;
   int regionSize = (int)IntPtr.Add((IntPtr)baseAddress, 
                                    (int)MemoryRegion[i].RegionSize);

   for (int mapAddress = baseAddress; mapAddress < regionSize; mapAddress++)
   {
      if (ReadMemory(process, mapAddress, buffer.Length).SequenceEqual(buffer))
         Console.WriteLine("Result: " + mapAddress.ToString("x8").ToUpper());
   }
}
```

Eso funciona a la perfección, primero obtengo las direcciones bases para cada bloque de memoria y sus largos, luego escaneo dirección por dirección en cada bloque de memoria lo que hace que tarde mucho.
Me gustaría entender y aprender como **Cheat Engine** escanea tan rápidamente, que método usa, que hago mal o que puedo mejorar.

Comment: Si me esta faltando información o detalles, por favor no me cierren la pregunta, díganme como puedo corregir la pregunta y que tipo de información ayudaría agregar. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La pregunta me la resolví a mi mismo, era muy obvio... En la noche tras una larga tarde de estrés al no encontrar la respuesta, simplemente intente dormir y no pude así que me pare hice café y comencé a repasar todo en mi pizarra.
Para mi sorpresa la respuesta del porque tanta lentitud era mas que obvia, estaba escaneando millones de direcciones una por una, en vez de obtener el bloque de memoria completo y hacer una función que identifique al array dentro de este bloque y así obtener la dirección en tan solo mili-segundos.

Si alguien tuvo el mismo problema no entiende lo que explico al 100% eres libre de pedirme código fuente y una explicación mas detallada, con gusto se las daré!